# Shrink string encoding algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, encoding, shrink

How do we shrink/encode a 20 letter string to 6 letters. I found few algorithms address data compression like RLE, Arithmetic coding, Universal code but none of them guarantees 6 letters.

The original string can contain the characters A-Z (upper case), 0-9 ans a dash.

Comment: If you want lossless encoding, it's impossible. There are 20^128 possible ASCII strings of length 20, and only 6^128 strings of length 6. There's no way you can cram the first category into the second.

Comment: Any restrictions on the type of 20 letter strings?

Comment: It's not possible to guarantee this. You can only compress strings that have some kind of repetition that can be encoded.

Comment: @Kevin You got the formulas backward. It's 128^20 and 128^6.

Comment: Oops, did I? Well, even so, the first number is bigger than the second, so my original point is still valid. Recommended reading: [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Uses_and_applications), in particular the bit that says, "any lossless compression algorithm, provided it makes some inputs smaller (as the name compression suggests), will also make some other inputs larger."

Comment: If you allow any 20-character string, then the other comments are correct; it's impossible. But if you can assume that the 20 input characters are all ASCII letters, with no control characters, you can play some tricks. You can subtract 0x40 from the value, so that the entire alphabet, upper and lower, fits into the range 0x01 to 0x3A. If you assume your input is only uppercase ASCII letters, that gives you even more bits to play with. Then treat the whole input as a series of bits and compress it down. The output chars will be in the range 0x01 to 0xFF and won't necessarily be printable.

Comment: Thanks for all comments, the allowed characters are A-Z, 0-9 and - Ex: 283F-233012931

Comment: @Ramu, "the allowed characters" are input characters, output characters, or both?

Comment: Hi Daniel, i didn't understand your question. Input is a string and encoded string. I have to encode given string and compare with given encoded string for validation. One way hash is also fine.

Comment: Oh! Using a one-way hash makes it much simpler to get within the boundaries.

Comment: @smk the restrictions are 1. All capital letters 2. All numbers 3. Can contain - (dash)

Comment: Initialize hash to 0.
`For each char in input:  
  hash = ((hash * 101) + char) mod 1000000  
`
When you're done, you'll have a hash between 0 and 999999, because of the mod.
Print that as a string, and that's your output.

Comment: @shoover I'm pretty sure OP wants something reversible (the usual meaning of the term "encode"), which is rather distinct from this sort of hash function...

Comment: @twalberg one way hashing is also okay, we don't need to decode string to original string. I'm trying as shoover suggested.

Comment: @shoover: And how to you propose to handle hash collisions?

Comment: @JimMischel OP didn't say whether collisions were allowed. OP is giving us information in dribs and drabs.

Comment: Can the string be *any combination* of those 20 characters? Or is there some format that says a dash can only occur in particular places, some positions must contain numbers, etc? Also, are the strings known to you in advance? Without some restriction on the strings, what you ask is not possible. You're trying to stuff 105 bits worth of information into 48 bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your goal is to *losslessly* compress or hash an random input string of 20 characters (each character could be [A-Z], [0-9] or -) to an output string of 6 characters. **It's theoretically impossible.**

In [information theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory), given a discrete random variable `X={x|x1,...,xn}`, the [Shannon entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon_entropy) `H(X)` is defined as:

[image]

where `p(xi)` is the probablity of `X = xi`. In your case, `X` has 20 of 37 possible characters, so it could be `{x|x1,...,xn}` where `n = 37^20`. Supposing the 37 characters have the same probability of being (aka the input string is random), then `p(xi) = 1/37^20`. So the Shannon entropy of the input is:

[image]

. A `char` in common computer can hold 8 bit, so that 6 chars can hold 48 bit. **There's no way to hold 104 bit information by 6 chars. You need at least 15 chars to hold it instead.**

---

If you do **allow the loss** and have to hash the 20 chars into 6 chars, then your are trying to hash `37^20` values to `128^6` keys. It could be done, but you would got plenty of [hash collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Uniformity).

In your case, supposing you hash them with the most uniformity (otherwise it would be worse), for each input value, there would be by average of 5.26 other input values sharing the same hash key with it. By a [birthday attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack), we could expect to find a collision within approximately 200 million trials. It could be done in less than 10 seconds by a common laptop. **So I don't think this would be a safe hashing.**

However if you insist to do that, you might want to read [Hash function algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hash_function_algorithms). It lists a lot of algorithms for your choice. Good luck!

Comment: Did OP state a requirement for losslessness?

Comment: @shoover I am editing to consider the case of loss:)