# Compression Algorithm for Guaranteed Compression Ratio?

Tags: algorithm, audio, compression, streaming

Can anyone offer me pointers or tips on finding/creating a data compression algorithm that has a **guaranteed compression ratio**? Obviously this couldn't be a loss-less algorithm.

My question is similar to the one here, but there was no suitable answer:

[Shrink string encoding algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765078/shrink-string-encoding-algorithm)

What I am trying to do is stream live audio over a wireless network (my own spec, not WiFi) with a tight bandwidth restriction. Let's say I have packets 60 bytes in size. I need an algorithm to compress these to, say, 35 bytes *every time without fail.* Reliable guaranteed compression to a fixed size is key. Audio quality is less of a priority.

Any suggestions or pointers? I may end up creating my own algorithm from scratch, so even if you don't know of any libraries or standard algorithms, I would be grateful for brilliant ideas of any kind!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shrink string encoding algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765078/shrink-string-encoding-algorithm)

Comment: Why is searching for "constant bitrate audio" not helping? Is there some reason you can't just use ffmpeg?

Comment: Fractal compression perhaps? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good that you mentioned your use case: live audio.

There are [many audio CODECs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_codecs) (COder-DECoder) that work exactly this way (constant bit-rate). For example, take a look at [Opus](http://opus-codec.org/). You can select bitrates from 6 kb/s to 510 kb/s, and frame sizes from 2.5 ms to 60 ms.

I used it in the past to tranfer audio over RF datalinks. You'll probably need to implement a de-jitter buffer as well (see more [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice/voice-quality/5125-delay-details.html)). Also note that the internal clock of many sound cards is not accurate, and there may be a "drift" between the source and target rate (e.g. a 30mSec buffer may be played in 29.9mSec or 30.1mSec) and you may need to compensate for this as well.